# Concatenate multiple files based on filename similarity : Windows Bash(Using Windows 10),Powershell, or Command Line)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash, powershell, file-management

I'm currently stuck in what seemed to be an easy task. I've been working on a python script that finds certain files in my Downloads folder and dumps them into another sub-folder within a different folder. Then, it converts the PDFs in that designated folder into text files since I will be extracting info from the files(and it's just way easier to work with TXT).

**Now, I'm stuck in this next part :** I have ~ 600 files (and will continue to have more) and want to combine files based on filename. This is how the filenames are formatted...

- Txt_BI_ProfilesBI_Profile_Export_BB+Generic_August+2016_GGP_20170316.pdf
- Txt_BI_BrofilesBI_Profile_Export_BB+Generic_August+2016_GGP_20170316.pdf (1)
- Txt_BI_ProfilesBI_Profile_Export_Search_20170228.pdf
- Txt_BI_ProfilesBI_Profile_Export_Search_20170228.pdf (1)

Note how there are files that share filename but are distinguishable with .pdf(1) . I need a powershell or bash script that groups and merges files into a consolidated text files based on filename similarity.

So given the filenames above, I want to merge all the content in

> ***'TxtBI_ProfilesBI_Profile_Export_BB+Generic_August+2016_GGP_20170316.pdf'*** + ***'Txt_BI_ProfilesBI_Profile_Export_BB+Generic_August+2016_GGP_20170316.pdf***
>   (1)' into a file = **'BB+Generic_August+2016_GGP'**

and same goes for 'Search'. For **'BB+Generic_August+2016_GGP'** and **'Search'** group there are up to about '.pdf(40)' different files, and there are about 10 or more different group of files that share similar filenames. I have written a python script that attempts to do this [here](https://codeshare.io/2EkQ7N) but all it's doing is splitting the filenames[33:] and filenames.rsplit('',1)[0] (splits after the 33 character and the last '_') and not combining them into consolidated files as I mentioned above. Can I do this with powershell or bash? Such that it splits filenames(as abovementioned) and then combines them If they hold the same text filenname?

I thought this was going to be super easy but it's not working for me. If anyone has any insight/ideas/suggestions on how to approach this, I would truly appreciate it! Have used bash in the past before for unix, but it's been a while. I'll go with whatever is most practical! Still a bit of a novice when it comes to programming....

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! I wouldn't lean too heavily on the 'programming' side of things, as programming is off-topic here. Do you actually want to concatenate the DF files themselves, or are you happy to instead combine the text files produced from them?

Comment: Gotcha, I'll def keep that in mind when asking questions on here! I'm not completely sure what the difference is? If this helps, I want to concatenate Group1_File + Group1_File (1) + Group1_File (2) ; Group2_File + Group2_ File (1) + Group2_File (2) into one file "Group1_File", Group2_File , respectively. I believe it gets difficult since ALL files share the same first 33 characters.

Comment: No problem- I'd argue the question itself is still on-topic as it's more to do with automation! The reason I ask as is that I'm not sure PDFs can be simply / sensibly concatenated together; whereas text files can.

Comment: Sorry if I was a little too vague...all these files were once PDF but then were converted to TEXT ( via a python script) and dumped into a folder.

Comment: You may want to perform this operation in python as well, in order to have one consistent script.

Comment: I would love to, but I have a deadline coming up so kinda need it asap. @simlev I'll try your suggestion in a bit, just have to enable bash on Windows 10(don't have it on this computer yet).

Comment: Ops, I thought you had bash ("I need a powershell or **bash** script")...in case you don't may I recommend [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org).

Comment: Yeah, I have it on my personal laptop just not here..i'm assuming your recommendation below works for both bash and Cygwin?

Comment: In powershell, you might find a useful combination of get-childitem, basename property, and -replace, for example `get-childitem | % { $newfile = $_.BaseName -replace 'txt_BI_etc',''; get-content $_.fullname >> "$newfile.txt" }

Comment: Hmm interesting...just tried this out and absolutely nothing is happening. No results or signs of execution on the powershell...

Comment: @Matthew That's a nice solution, you should post a full-fledged answer that illustrates Powershell's capabilities. As it is, it gets stuck in a loop and does not, yet, produce the exact desired output filenames.

Comment: @GGp Cygwin is just one of the (best) ways to have a bash, UNIX-like environment on Windows. The answer pertains to bash (meaning, a UNIX-like command-line environment).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** better solution that produces the desired output file names

Making use of `ls`, `awk` and `cat`:

```
ls | awk '! /\([0-9]+\)/ {match($0, /Txt_BI_ProfilesBI_Profile_Export_([^.]+)/,matches); system("cat " $0 "* >"matches[1] ".txt")}'
```

Prompted by Matthew's display of Powershell's powers, I *had* to show the same can be achieved in a bash environment. This is just one of the many ways, as is common in the UNIX world.

**Explanation:**

`ls` lists all elements in the current directory

`awk` programming language designed for text processing

`! /\([0-9]+\)/` exclude filenames that contain a number in parentheses

`match($0, /Txt_BI_ProfilesBI_Profile_Export_([^.]+)/,matches)` perform a regular expression match on the filename, capturing the part between the common prefix and the first dot

`system("` execute a system command

`cat " $0 "*` concatenate files that start with the filename

`>"matches[1] ".txt"` output to a file named like the captured expression and having a .txt extension

---

**First answer:**
You can use `find`, `xargs`, `bash` and `cat`:

```
find . -type f -regextype sed ! -regex "\./.*([0-9]\+)" | xargs -I{} bash -c 'cat {}* > {}.txt'
```

This is more of a proof-of-concept and could be refined, as the output filenames are not exactly what you sought, but should be enough to solve your problem in the immediate.

**Explanation:**

`find .` search the current directory

`-type f` look for files

`-regextype sed` use the regular expression engine with sed-compatible syntax

`! -regex "\./.*([0-9]\+)"` exclude results that match the specified regular expression, i.e. those that include a number in parentheses at the end

`| xargs` use each result to construct a command

`-I{}` in the following command, substitute `{}` with each `find` result

`bash -c` pass the following string as a command to `bash`

`'cat {}* > {}.txt'` concatenate the files that start with the found filename into a file that has a name made up from the `find` result and the `.txt` extension

Comment: After your post, I have been digging up on bash(it's been AWHILE since I last used it)...few questions though. (1) For, `match($0, /Txt_BI_ProfilesBI_Profile_Export_([^.]+)/,matches)` in the edited version, can I use substitute `([^.+])` with `([^.pdf+])`?...since some of the filenames have a " . " in the area between the common prefix  and `.pdf`...(2) Is there a way to specify the concatenated output-file's directory? (3) This might be a VERY rudimentary question, and I apologize if it is...before executing the script, I have to `cd` to where the files are located, correct?

Comment: I strongly feel you should be able to make these trivial adjustments yourself. (1) I'd use `(.+).pdf`. (2) specify the output directory after the `>`. (3) yes, or use `find inputdirectory -type f` instead of `ls`.